# lodash - Group/sum two arrays into object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have two arrays (one of keys and one of values) that I want to group into an object with summing the values when keys are identical.

```
var keys = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'];
var values = [1, 2, 2, 3];
```

I have tryed using lodash `zibObject()` but there is not way to sum the value with this function. I guess using `zipWith()` would be the solution, but I dont know how to sum.

```
var grouped = _.zipWith(keys, values, function(a,b){
    return {a: b}; // not summing: [{a: 1}, {b: 2}, {a, 2}, {c: 3}]
});
```

but what I want is:

```
var result = {
    a: 3,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
};
```

What would be the proper way to achieve that with lodash?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. I don't see how the keys and values arrays are tied together. How did you get `a` is 3, `b` is 2, and `c` is 3?

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_.reduce(keys, function(result, key, index){
    result[key] = result[key] ? result[key] + values[index] : values[index];
    return result;
}, {})
```

Comment: slightly better than @Andy answer

Answer (score 2):

without lodash or underscore

```js
var keys = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'];
var values = [1, 2, 2, 3];
var grouped = {};

if (keys.length !== values.length) throw "array don't match!!"
for (var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i++) {
  grouped[keys[i]] = grouped[keys[i]] + values[i] || values[i];
}
document.getElementById('final').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(grouped);
```

```html
<pre id="final"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`_.reduce`](https://lodash.com/docs#reduce) using an object as the initial value:

```js
const keys = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'];
const values = [1, 2, 2, 3];

// If `acc[c]` doesn't exist set it to zero
// then add one to it.
const out = _.reduce(keys, (acc, c, i) => {
  acc[c] ??= 0;
  acc[c] += values[i];
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(out);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

But you may as well use native JS for this in 2022.

```js
const keys = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'];
const values = [1, 2, 2, 3];

const out = keys.reduce((acc, c, i) => {
  acc[c] ??= 0;
  acc[c] += values[i];
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(out);
```

Or even just a simple loop

```js
const keys = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'];
const values = [1, 2, 2, 3];

const out = {};

for (const [i, key] of keys.entries()) {
  out[key] ??= 0;
  out[key] += values[i];
}

console.log(out);
```

Additional documentation

- [Logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)

Comment: If performance matters, it seems that [vanilla is fastest](http://jsperf.com/merge-sum-arrays)

Comment: @PatrickFerreira fastest safe better than fastest solution.